# Special drop shadow: Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, png

In the image below, I have two types of drop shadows.

In swift, I've used this function:

```
func applyShadow(view: UIView){
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
    view.clipsToBounds = false
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

to apply the shadow to the image in the image view.

*How can I modify the applyShadow function to make the iOS drop-shadow match the effect of the web one?*

I'm using .png files, but if I had to convert the file format, It wouldn't be too much more work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here just think of **view.layer.shadowOffset** as the fourth quadrant of 2 dimensional coordinate system. So if the value for that is **CGSizeMake(0, 0)**, the shadow will spread in all the sides equally.

Now **view.layer.shadowRadius** is just the radius or reach of the shadow. By changing its value, the shadow length will change.

**view.layer.shadowOpacity** will change the darkness of the shadow. Its value change from 0 to 1.

Suppose we set the **shadowOffset as CGSizeMake(5, 0)** and **shadowRadius as something less than 5**, then the shadow will move to the right side of the object and there will not be any shadows in other sides. Suppose the value is **CGSizeMake(0, 5)**, the shadow will be at the bottom of the object, i.e. it will move 5 points down and there will not be any shadows in other sides. So in that way if value is **CGSizeMake(5, 5)**, the shadow will move bottom-left direction 5 points.

I think you got a better understanding of this. So when comes back to your problem, I think this will work:

```
func applyShadow(view: UIView){
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(8, 12)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
func applyShadow(view: UIView){
    let offset = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width + offset.width, y: view.frame.size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width + offset.width, y: view.frame.size.height + offset.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width, y: view.frame.size.height + offset.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowPath = path.cgPath
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

You might need to fiddle around with `offset`, `shadowOpacity`, and `shadowRadius` a little bit more to get as close as possible, but these values are pretty close when I debug locally.

Also, you don't need to do `view.clipsToBounds` and `view.layer.masksToBounds` at the same time. Those are pretty much interchangeable and if you set one, the other should be updated automatically.